# Creating a ".bat" file, run it and delete it from Java

Tags: java, multithreading, runtime.exec

I'm making a `.bat` dynamically in `Java`.

After creating the file and exectuing it, I want to delete it.

In order to make sure that `delete()` will be executing after running the `.bat` file, I delete the file within a different thread.

Is this a good approach for this task? How would you implement it in a better way?

```
final File file = new File("run.bat");
file.createNewFile();
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(file, "UTF-8");
writer.println(COMMAND1);
writer.println(COMMAND2);

.... ANOTHER COMMANDS

writer.close();
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start a.bat");

new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        file.delete();
    }
}).run();
```

Comment: If you want to make sure it is deleted after the execution, you should wait for the execution to finish and then delete it.

Comment: If you have access to the bat files you can make it [delete itself](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2888976/238902 "How to make .BAT file delete it self after completion?")

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wouldnt delete the file in a different thread, what if the file execution is still running at the time you try to delete it?

I would consider asking the [exit code](http://ss64.com/nt/exit.html) from the file, or use a process.waitFor() which causes the current thread to wait, if necessary, until the process represented by this Process object has terminated.

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start a.bat");
p.waitFor();
file.delete();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this which causes the code to wait until the batch file execution is complete before deleting the file.

```
Process batchFileExecutionProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start a.bat");
batchFileExecutionProcess.waitFor();
file.delete();
```

Ideally, you would build error handling into this solution as well, such as looking for a 0 return from the waitFor() method.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not good approach. Actually I don't see any advantage of the extra thread. Most likely it will attempt to delete the file while it's still being used by `cmd` and deletion will fail.
Instead you should use `Process` object (the result of `exec()`) and wait until the it finished and delete the file then:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start a.bat");
p.waitFor();
file.delete()
```