# how to remove the batch file you just used

Tags: batch-file, command-prompt

How do I remove a batch file I just used with a batch code line?
Like a code that does this:

```
remove thisbat.bat
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do what this guy does: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888976/how-to-make-bat-file-delete-it-self-after-completion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some people will tell you to just put

```
DEL "%~f0"
```

on the last line, but that usually causes an error in that the BAT file can no longer find itself.  You should use the following statement on the **last** line of your BAT file, because after it hits this line your BAT file is gone:

```
start /b "" cmd /c del "%~f0"&exit /b
```

This will launch a new delete process within the same console, thus eliminating any "file can no longer be found" errors.