# ClickOnce application how to auto start up after login

Tags: clickonce, startup

I would like to have application auto start up after login.
something like you have start up links.

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical approach is to add a shortcut to the user's Startup folder or add a new registry key from you application code. It's a hack though because it won't be removed on uninstall.

Here's [more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401816).

Answer (score 2):

As @codeConcussion said you can make your application launch on start up using various solutions (add shortcut to start up group or update startup registry entry), but there's clean up problem. [You can take a look on my article, where this issue is solved.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/506162/ClickOnce-application-autostart-clean-uninstall-or)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass command line parameters with ClickOnce.  You could have one normal link and then one link that contains a command line parameter that you can read in the startup to activte the app after they login (or any action you want).