# Autostart click-once winform application network deployed

Tags: c#, winforms, autostart

I need to autostart my c# click-once winform application, but such that when autostarted that it is still ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed = true.

Currently i autostart my app using:

```
 RegistryKey rkApp = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
 if (!IsStartupItem())
                // Add the value in the registry so that the application runs at startup
                rkApp.SetValue("myApp", Application.ExecutablePath.ToString());
```

But when application is started i get ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed = false

Answer (score 0):

I found solution that makes application network deployed.

```
// The path to the key where Windows looks for startup applications
RegistryKey rkApp = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(
                    @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run", true);

//Path to launch shortcut
string startPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Programs) 
                   + @"\YourPublisher\YourSuite\YourProduct.appref-ms";

rkApp.SetValue("YourProduct", startPath);
```

The solution is from post [How can I make a Click-once deployed app run at startup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401816/how-can-i-make-a-click-once-deployed-app-run-at-startup)